# C++ : Интересны многие методы возведения в степень

Tags: c++

Доброго дня интересуют частые способы возведения в степень.
В особенности случай когда O(logn),O(n²),O(n).

Последний наверное обычное через цикл и арифметические действия.

O(n²) наверное через рекурсию.

А вот первая меня очень интересует,я думал что это может быть подключение библиотеки c.math,и использование функции pow.Но не уверен.

Впрочем подскажите и просвятите в эту.И да я новичок.

Comment: Рекурсия ничем от итерации тут отличаться не будет, кроме расхода памяти на стек и немного переделанного алгоритма.

Comment: O(logN) это чуть менее чем всегда дерево. Исходи из этого.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Насчет **алгоритма за `O(n)`** вы правы. Обычное умножение числа `m` само на себя `k` раз.

**Алгоритм работающий за `O(logn)`** это например бинарное возведение в степень.

Его суть в том, что если показатель степени четный, то для любого основания верно тождество:

```
a ^ n = (a ^ (n / 2)) ^ 2 = (a ^ (n / 2)) * (a ^ (n / 2))
```

Если же показатель нечетный, то верно тождество:

```
a ^ n = a ^ (n - 1) * a, где n - 1 является четным показателем степени
```

Приведу лишь один пример с отличного сайта (который приведу ниже):

```
int binpow(int a, int n) {
    int res = 1;
    while (n) {
        //Проверяем если n нечетное, то умножаем результат на a
        if (n & 1)
            res *= a;
        a *= a;
        n >>= 1;
    }
    return res;
}
```

Например пусть `a = 2, n = 5`, при обычном алгоритме мы бы делали так:

```
res = 2 * 2 * 2 * 2 * 2 = 32
```

При бинарном возведении в степени в данном случае на одну двойку сразу умножим, потом рассчитаем `2 * 2 = 4` и зная, что показатель степени четный (т.к. одну двойку сразу умножили) мы сразу посчитаем `4 * 4 = 16`, а потом получим:

```
res = 2 * 2 * 2 * 2 * 2 = 2 * 4 * 4 = 2 * 16 = 32
```

Надеюсь понятно объяснил, но в любом случае на сайте будет еще понятней: [ссылка](https://e-maxx.ru/algo/binary_pow)

Так же есть алгоритм, которому требуется в среднем `logn / 2` операций умножения в отличии от стандартного алгоритма, где требуется `n - 1` операций умножения. Расписывать его не стану, лишь оставлю ссылку на статью в [википедии](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%90%D0%BB%D0%B3%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%BC%D1%8B_%D0%B1%D1%8B%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE_%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B7%D0%B2%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F_%D0%B2_%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BF%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%8C).

А насчет алгоритм за `O(n^2)` честно не слышал о таком :), но и зачем только такой нужен.